# Why can C main function be coded with or without parameters?

Tags: c

Just wondering why this

```
int main(void){}
```

compiles and links

and so does this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){}
```

Why isn't it required to be one or the other?

gcc will even compile and link with one argument:

```
int main(int argc){}
```

but issue this warning with -Wall:

```
smallest_1.5.c:3:1: warning: ‘main’ takes only zero or two arguments [-Wmain]
```

I am not asking this as in "how come they allow this?" but as in "how does the caller and the linker handle multiple possibilities for main?"

Comment: The short answer is "because the standard says so".

Comment: @JefferyThomas My question wasn't along the lines of "why do they allow it" but "how does it work"? How is it that the caller routine and the linker can both handle either kind of definition?

Comment: Because the calling code can, for example, pass arguments in registers or on the stack. The two argument main uses them, while the zero argument main does nothing with them. It's that simple. Linking does not even come into the picture.

Comment: Very related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372286/how-crt-calls-main-having-different-parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making it work has to do with the [binary format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Executable_file_formats) of the [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) and the OS's [loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_(computing)). The linker doesn't care (well it cares a little: it needs to mark the entry point) and the only caller routine is the loader.

The loader for any system must know how to bring supported binary format into memory and branch into the entry point. This varies slightly by system and binary format.

---

If you have a question about a particular OS/binary format, you may want to clarify.

Answer (score 9):

<sup>I am taking a Linux point of view below.</sup>

The `main` function is very special in the standard definition (for hosted C11 implementations). It is also explicitly known by recent compilers (both [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) & [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)....) which have specific code to handle `main` (and to give you this warning). BTW, GCC (with help from [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) headers thru [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)) has also special code for `printf`. And you could add your own customization to GCC using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) for your own function attributes.

For the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29), `main` is often a usual symbol, but it is called from [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) (compile your code using `gcc -v` to understand what that really means). BTW, the [ld(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html) linker (and [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) files, e.g. [executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) or [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_code)) has no notion of types or function signatures and deals only with names (This is why C++ compilers do some [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)).

And the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and the [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) are so defined that passing unused arguments to a function (like `main` or even [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)...) does not do any harm (several arguments get passed in registers). Read the [x86-64 System V ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) for details.

See also the references in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28187216/841108).

At last, you really should practically define your `main` as `int main(int argc, char**argv)` and nothing else, and you hopefully should [handle](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html) program arguments thru them (at least `--help`  & `--version` as mandated by [GNU coding standards](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Command_002dLine-Interfaces)). On Linux, I *hate* programs (and I curse their programmers) not doing that (so *please* handle `--help` & `--version`).

Answer (score 2):

Because the calling code can, for example, pass arguments in registers or on the stack. The two argument main uses them, while the zero argument main does nothing with them. It's that simple. Linking does not even enter the picture.

If you are worried about stack adjustments in the called code, the `main` function just needs to make sure the stack pointer is the same when it returns (and often even this is of no importance, e.g. when the ABI states that the caller is responsible for stack management).

Answer (score 1):

> The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no parameters:
>
> `int main(void) { /* ... */ }`
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }`
>
> or equivalent; or in some other implementation-defined manner.

### Regarding the parameters:

> The **first counts the arguments** supplied to the program and the **second is an array of pointers to the strings which are those arguments**. These arguments are passed to the program by the command line interpreter.
>   So, the two possibilities are handled as:
>
> 1. If no parameters are declared: no parameters are expected as input.
> 2. If there are parameters in `main()` ,they should:
>
>    - `argc` is greater than zero.
>    - `argv[argc]` is a null pointer.
>    - `argv[0]` through to `argv[argc-1]` are pointers to strings whose meaning will be determined by the program.
>    - `argv[0]` will be a string containing the program's name or a null string if that is not available. Remaining elements of `argv` represent the arguments supplied to the program. In cases where there is only support for single-case characters, the contents of these strings will be supplied to the program in lower-case.

### In memory:

they will be placed on the stack just above the return address and the saved base pointer (just as any other stack frame).

### At machine level:

they will be passed in registers, depending on the implementation.

Comment: But C does not allow overloading functions.

Comment: @el.pescado Reminding you that I've written "one can think of of the `main()` ..." . However, that is a nice question!

Comment: There's pitfall, however, in that generalization. Function overloading works usually by appending function signature to symbol name (e.g. by name mangling in C++), so that two functions, albeit having same name, are assgined different symbols. In this case, it works because no such thing happens - any form of "main" has the same symbol name ("main" or "_main" in most cases).

Comment: Moreover, although any form of `main` may work, still you can have only one.

Comment: @el.pescado thanks for the insight!  I'll paraphrase the introduction to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: if you don't use the parameters, then you can declare main without parameters, in two ways:

```
int main(void)
```

or

```
int main()
```

The first means `main` is a function with no parameters. The second means `main` is a function with any number of parameters.

Since you don't access the parameters, both will be fine. Any compiler having "special" code to check the parameters of `main` is wrong. (But: `main` *must* return a value.)

Comment: TIL. Interestingly this is one other aspect in which C differs from C++ i.e. a function taking parameters in the definition can still be declared without any in the declaration. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/287002/331025