# Start of C program passes parameters to int main(void)

Tags: c, parameters, program-entry-point

During a C program, the functions that are invoked before the main function call it with the parameters from the command line. However, how is this done with a function that is declared as int main(void) without errors, as it still calls the function with parameters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can C main function be coded with or without parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32550081/why-can-c-main-function-be-coded-with-or-without-parameters)

Comment: I had read that post and still didn't get how it worked.

Comment: Internally, functions ignore extra arguments that they aren't expecting.

Comment: Does this only apply the main method, as when testing this, a compilation error for too many parameters occurred.

Comment: I assume you're thinking in terms of `stdcall`? With `cdecl` it isn't important what kind of arguments are passed.

Comment: I was thinking in the terms stdcall

Comment: Are you asking for taking input from the command line i.e command-line arguments??

Comment: @ainam2005 It applies to any function, but the compiler won't let you compile a call if it doesn't match the function declaration. The reason you can do it with `main()` is because you don't write the call anywhere in your program, it's called automatically by the run-time library, which is already compiled.

Comment: If you want to see it happen with a user-defined function, put the function definition and call in two different `.c` files. Define the function with no arguments, but declare it with 2 arguments in the calliing file.